# UITableView separator style missing lines

Tags: ios, uitableview, bounds

My code below prints the tableview array fine. However the separator lines are missing. As You can see in the photo below. This question has been asked before but I have not found a solution using any of the prior questions.

[image]

Comment: Are you running in a scaled iOS simulator?

Comment: Can you post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method in question OR you're using Storyboard completely?

Comment: as rmadday said This is simulator , run in actual device you will able to see it or increase size of simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please run the app in device ,it will be fine

Comment: it's due to some simulator graphic issues

Answer (score 1):

sometime Simulator does not show the separator line . because of resolution. but in device separator line show please test in the device.